# HP pavilion dv6 blank screen, power but no hd Led

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, battery

I have been dealing with this HP dv6 all day with no luck. Working fine yesterday but today I get nothing but a blank screen. I can hear fan come on, and a few keyboard lights come on, but nothing on screen... Not even bios. I've tried a hard reset, removing CMOS battery, swapping out ram modules and still nothing. Does anyone have a suggestion on what to do next? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem right last week. You should check your keyboard for clues. Mine got the cap-lock light flashing (1 flash followed by a «long» wait, repeat).

On HP website, it says there's a problem with the processor. I contacted HP customer support and the guy told me that it would cost 280$ to get the motherboard and processor fixed (cause they change both at once), that price including shipping and taxes.

Since the price was kinda high, i ordered a new processor(55$) and changed it myself. Nothing changed so i guess the motherboard is the problem.

You could/should check it out.

Good luck!